# Help translating .htaccess to web.config url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config

What would this rewrite rule from .htaccess translate to IIS7 web.config?

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: Uh, in other words (read: in technically correct terms), you actually want to convert an Apache-specific RewriteRule into an ISAPI-specific RewriteRule?

Comment: What was the reason for adding the passthrough [PT] flag to the rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test it right now but hopefully

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="some unnamed rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

isn't too wrong...

Comment: By the way, in IIS7 there is a place for you to paste .htaccess rewrites and IIS7 will automatically convert it! Just found it.

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 and above can import Apache .htaccess rules using the **URL Rewrite module**.

1. Install the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691) via the *Microsoft Web Platform Installer*
2. Start IIS Manager and on the left, in the Connections pane, select your required site (e.g. Default Web Site)
3. In the centre (Features View) double click **URL Rewrite**.
4. In the right panel click **Import Rules...** then paste your rules from the .htaccess file into the **Rewrite rules** box
5. Click apply in the right column.